# Regular Expression Username and City Pattern

Tags: asp.net

I want to Validate **UserName** and **City** field like this that an user can enter numbers,+,@,#, and $ characters

Please provide any help to make this regular expression

Comment: `UserCan enter number,+@#$ characters` vs. `Not Acceptable number +@#$ Character`. Your requirements contradict themseves. Please state your requirements *clearly*, show what work you have done so far and which MSDN pages you have read, and where exactly you are stuck and need help.

Comment: I think he meant that it can contain those characters but also at least one digit. Even if it doesn't seem like city or username input.

Comment: Put some examples of valid cities and invalid ones also www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: Sorry done it wrong user can enter +@#$ characters and also number

Comment: and also normal characters?

Comment: Which city name consists only of numbers, +, @, # and $?

Answer (score 0):

```
ValidationExpression="[\d+@#$]+"
```

Comment: give regular expression which i will use in asp regular expression validator